# How can you make a PDE solution stabilize over time?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde

this is a problem I have been thinking about lately. I tried asking on stack exchange as well but did not find an answer.

Suppose I have a simple linear first order PDE of the form:
$$au_x+bu_y=0$$
I want to create a PDE in 3 variables, $x,y,t$ (so the function is now $u(x,y,t)$) such that given an initial condition $u(x,y,0)=u_0(x,y)$ (depending on just the first two variables):

1. If $u_0$ satisfies the original PDE, then the solution to the new PDE is equal to $u_0$ at all times.
2. Generally, as $t\rightarrow \infty$, the solution to the new PDE converges to a function of just two variables $u(x,y)$ which satisfies the original PDE. (converges in what topology? Naturally I'd prefer the topology to be as strong as possible, but I'm open to anything interesting)

So in a sense, I want my PDE to stabilize over time to a PDE of 'less' variables. For instance, I can create a PDE which satisfies the first condition by writing:
$$u_t=au_x+bu_y$$
But it does not generally satisfy the 2nd condition (I checked). A relevant example which comes to mind is the heat equation, which usually stabilizes over time to a harmonic function (which is the stationary solution). But I want something which fits my specific first order PDE. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

This is the first part of my question. The harder part is (and this is actually what I'm really interested in) - if we can find such a method for the PDE above, can we generalize this method for a system of 2 coupled PDE's of the form:
$$au_x+bv_y=0$$
$$cu_y+dv_x=0$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason this works for the heat equation is that it is the gradient flow of the Dirichlet-energy $E(u) := \frac12 \int |\nabla u|^2$, i.e. harmonic functions are minimizers for that energy and the heat equation is its formal $L^2$-gradient flow $\partial_t u = - \nabla E(u)$, which tends to "flow downhill". This generalizes quite well to different energies and is one of the standard tools for (non-linear) PDEs. However the problem is that your PDE is not variational, i.e. not related to an energy in this way, so this approach won't work.

Comment: @mlk That's a very good observation, I guess that this makes the problem more difficult. Is there a way to know for sure that such an energy functional does not exist for my problem? (maybe it could have a different form?)

Comment: The way the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation works, if there is an energy functional, you always end up with highest derivatives of even order, which is clearly not the case for your equation. Now there might be some trick that I don't know, like a different equation of second order with the same solution, but honestly I would be a bit surprised.